# Why does the history.push not work with the button click? It simply does not forward me

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

My problem is that history.push just does not work. It just doesn't forward me after clicking the button? How can you solve this? Or what is my thinking error? If I also set up a state for the forwarding it does not work either. Does anyone have any idea how to do this with history.push?

```
const LoginPage: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");

    const history = useHistory();

    const handleEmailChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const newEmail = event.target.value
        setEmail(newEmail)
    }

    const handlePasswordChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const newPassword = event.target.value
        setPassword(newPassword)
    }

    const { isAuthenticated } = React.useContext(TokenContext);

    const loginClick = () => {
        axios.post('/api/users/auth', {
            email: email,
            password: password
        }).then(res => {
            history.push("/dashboard")
            localStorage.setItem("jwt-token", res.data.token);
        })
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {isAuthenticated ? <Redirect to="/dashboard" /> :
                <TextField
                     label="Email Address"
                     name="email"
                     onChange={handleEmailChange}
                   />
                   <TextField
                     name="password"
                     label="Password"
                     type="password"
                     onChange={handlePasswordChange}
                    />
                    <Button
                      onClick={() => loginClick()}
                      variant="contained"
                      style={{ color: "white", backgroundColor: COLORS.primary }}
                      >
                    Anmelden
                   </Button>
            }
        </React.Fragment >
    )
}
```

Comment: I can't tell off the bat what the issue is, unfortunately. However, here's something that will help flush it into the open: can you log something before sending the POST request (like `console.log('before request')`), and then log something different before calling `history.push`? This will let us see (1) whether this method is called, and (2) whether the callback to `.then` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Your loginClick function is an async function, meaning that you have to wait for the axios function to resolve, return the server response and then do something with the data.

You could write it like this:

```
const loginClick = async() => {
        await axios.post('/api/users/auth', {
            email: email,
            password: password
        }).then(res => {
            history.push("/dashboard")
            localStorage.setItem("jwt-token", res.data.token);
        })
    }
```

Or even better

```
const loginClick = async() => {
    let res = await axios.post('/api/users/auth', {
        email: email,
        password: password
    }).then(data => {
        return data;
    })
    .catch((error)=> {
      console.log(error);
    });
    history.push("/dashboard");
    localStorage.setItem("jwt-token", res.data.token);
```

}